# "Наслаждался всей информацией" - is it correct?

Tags: грамматика

is the word 'information' countable or uncountable in the Russian language?
as a clarifying example, is it grammatically correct to say 'я наслаждался всей информацией'?

Comment: actually your example is not about countable/uncountable dichotomy.

Comment: would you may be want to say: "пользовался (воспользовался) всей (доступной, полученной) информацией"? Cause what you are trying to say is: "(I) took pleasure in (enjoyed) all the information", instead of "(I) took advantage of (used) all the information".

Comment: @shabunc my example helps to clarify the difference between the countable and uncountable since here информация can't be put like информациями (a plural noun in instrumental case) . that's what i wanted to make sure about.

Comment: @DaryaShcherbakova the whole sentence that was in mind is 'я наслаждался всей информацией, которую нам предоставили во время лекций', as in 'I enjoyed all the information we were given during the lectures' but I only shortened it because it was irrelevant to what I was wondering about at first, but as a side note regarding choosing the proper verb, do you see the sentence lacking the eloquence as it's written above?

Comment: @Yaman Kh, we would usually say "Мне понравились лекции - I enjoyed the lectures" or "Меня сильно заинтересовала информация, которую я узнал (получил) на лекциях - I was interested in the information that I received during the lectures". Somehow we don't really say "I enjoyed the information", even in English is sounds a bit weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not countable, but the nouns **вся** / **половина** / **часть** don't imply countability and so are totally permissible in combination with **информация**.

What you can't say is **две информации** or **много информаций** and the like.

As far as the expression **я наслаждался всей информацией** is concerned, it doesn't really sound idiomatic albeit being fully comprehensible. Not because of the presence of **всей**, but because it's lacking a complement such as **всей** **`этой/найденной/полученной`** **информацией** or **всей информацией,** **`которую/которая/которой ...`** etc. So **информация** requires some type of specification.
And also because the very notion of relishing information is pretty quaint.

Comment: my core inquiry was to make sure whether информация is countable or not, like in the English language, but the whole sentence I had in mind was 'я наслаждался всей информацией, которую нам предоставили во время лекций'.

Comment: @Yaman Kh OK, that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

> is the word 'information' countable or uncountable in the Russian language?

Uncountable.
You can not say [one information], [two informations], [10 informations].
You can say [all information], [not all information], [no information].
You can say [a little information], [a lot of information].
You can say [some information].
You can say [10% of information], [a half of information], [3/4 of information].

> is it grammatically correct to say 'я наслаждался всей информацией'?

It is 100% correct to say that.
If you say that in Russia, people will understand you 100%.

> 'я наслаждался всей информацией, которую нам предоставили во время лекций'

It is 100% correct to say that.
If you say that in Russia, people will understand you 100%.

---

### Just some thoughts

Word [информация] and [предоставили] are pretty cold, official and uncomfortable.
When Russians hear words [информация] and and [предоставили] - it is something about office world, it is something about communication of people which have long social distance between them.

More natural (or more warm) forms of the same idea.

> 'я наслаждался всем, что нам предоставили во время лекций'
>   'я наслаждался всем, что нам рассказывали и показывали во время лекций'

Word [наслаждаться] are pretty polite and too royal.
It's a word from vocabulary of people who have the heighest cultural level of personal development and education.
It is a word for people from high society.

Simple people in this case say something like.

> я кайфовал от каждой лекции!
>   лекции были безумно интересные!
>   лекции были просто обалденные!
>   лекции были реально огонь!